# Stream Process Scraped Audio in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I'd like to scrape multiple audio channels from a website. I'd like to do the following simultaneously and in real-time:

```
1. Save the audio to GCP Storage. 
2. Apply speech-to-text ML and send transcripts to an app.
```

I'd like to focus on (1) for this post. What's the best way to do this in GCP, is it Pubsub? If not, what's the best way to architect this?

I have a functional Python script.

Setup recording function.

```
def record(url): 
  # Open url. 
  response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  block_size = 1024

  # Make folder with station name. 
  # Example, 'www.music.com/station_1' has folder name of '/station_1/'
  channel = re.search('([^\/]+$)' , url)[0]
  folder = '/' + channel + '/'
  os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(folder), exist_ok=True)

  # Run indefinitely
  while True:
    # Name recording as the current date_time. 
    filename = folder + time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y--%H-%M-%S") + '.mp3'
    f = open(filename, 'wb')

    start = time.time()
    # Create new file every 60 seconds. 
    while time.time() - start < 60:
      buffer = response.read(block_size)
      f.write(buffer)
    f.close()
```

Declare URLs to record

```
urls = ['www.music.com/station_1',...,'www.music.com/station_n']
```

Thread to record from multiple URLs at once.

```
p = Pool(len(urls))
p.map(record, urls)
p.terminate()
p.join()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beam will not be a good fit for such a usecase.

Explanation:

Assuming that channel name is the element.

Your example requires processing of a single element indefinitely which is something not very well done by beam.

Even if we define each element as (channel name, timestamp), the problem will not be solved as we can not pull data based on station for arbitrary time window.